# How to create an invoice template

Tags: azure-logic-apps

Not sure if this is even possible, but what I'm looking to do create an invoice template via some SQL output and send them out as emails.

What I have tried so far is run a piece of SQL that contains all the details of an invoice, parse it as JSON, then create a csv table and lastly send them out via email with a CSV as an attachment.

The issue that I'm facing is that it's pretty basic; I would like to create a template of sorts and later converted to a PDF.

I'm moving away from SSRS and trying to use a logic app for the first time so not sure if this is something even achievable.

Appreciate any tips/help. Thanks in advance.

Regards

Comment: You can have a Word template and populate the data that way and then you can convert the Word document to a PDF.  That's the basic thinking anyway.

Comment: Cheers Skin, I ended up using word -- completely forgot about it!

Comment: That contradicts the fact that you flagged the below answer which uses Excel … but ok.

Comment: I can't seem to flag yours.

Comment: That's because mine isn't an answer.  If you didn't use the answer though, you don't flag it, simple.

Comment: I felt bad, the person put in effort :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to use to `Create CSV table` with Custom Headers from Sql connector `Get rows (V2)` action and then convert it to Excel using 3rd party connector **Plumsail's** `Csv to Excel` action to transform the results of it into pdf using `Convert Excel to PDF` action of **Adobe PDF services** Connector.

Below is the flow of my logic app where I receive a sorted csv's pdf in my email attachments.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

***TABLE IN SQL DATABASE***

[image]

***RESULT IN LOGIC APP***

[image]

***RESULT IN MAIL***

[image]

To reproduce the same in your logic app, you can use below code view

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Convert_Excel_to_PDF": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "$content-type": "multipart/form-data",
                        "$multipart": [
                            {
                                "body": "EXCEL_TO_PDF",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"intent\""
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "body": "pdfFile.xlsx",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"inputFileName\""
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "body": "@body('Csv_to_Excel')",
                                "headers": {
                                    "Content-Disposition": "form-data; name=\"InputFile0\""
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "headers": {
                        "x-api-key": "PowerAutomate"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['adobepdftools']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/operation/v1/createPDFFromExcel"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Csv_to_Excel": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Create_CSV_table": {
                "inputs": {
                    "columns": [
                        {
                            "header": "BillNo",
                            "value": "@item()?['billNo']"
                        },
                        {
                            "header": "OrderedDate",
                            "value": "@item()?['orderedDate']"
                        },
                        {
                            "header": "OrderValue",
                            "value": "@item()?['orderValue']"
                        }
                    ],
                    "format": "CSV",
                    "from": "@body('Get_rows_(V2)')?['value']"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Get_rows_(V2)": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Table"
            },
            "Csv_to_Excel": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "content": "@{base64(body('Create_CSV_table'))}",
                        "hasHeaderRecords": true
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['plumsail_3']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/flow/v1/Documents/jobs/Csv2Xlsx"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Create_CSV_table": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Get_rows_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "get",
                    "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('default'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[dbo].[Invoices]'))}/items",
                    "queries": {
                        "$orderby": "billNo asc"
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Attachments": [
                            {
                                "ContentBytes": "@{body('Convert_Excel_to_PDF')?['fileContent']}",
                                "Name": "@body('Convert_Excel_to_PDF')?['fileName']"
                            }
                        ],
                        "Body": "<p>This is a sample email</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "Sample",
                        "To": "<TO_MAIL_ID>"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365_1']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Convert_Excel_to_PDF": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Minute",
                    "interval": 3
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "adobepdftools": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/adobepdftools-4",
                    "connectionName": "adobepdftools-4",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/adobepdftools"
                },
                "office365_1": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365-1",
                    "connectionName": "office365-1",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/office365"
                },
                "plumsail_3": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/plumsail-3",
                    "connectionName": "plumsail-3",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/plumsail"
                },
                "sql": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/resourceGroups/<RG>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/sql",
                    "connectionName": "sql",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/<SUB_ID>/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/centralus/managedApis/sql"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---